# hey, i would like to make a Selenium Bot in Python that solves Driving School questions

Tags: python, selenium

How to fetch the questionNumber with Selenium?

I already have this
like I already have the login process but I want to fetch the question numbers to google them and return the answers found on google.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.windrive-theorietrainer.de/tt/questionnaires/category/questionnaire/3")
time.sleep(5)
lol = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
lol.send_keys("email@example.com")
lol = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
lol.send_keys("1233123123")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()

driver.execute_script("window.open('" + "https://www.windrive-theorietrainer.de/tt/questionnaires/exercise/questionnaire" +"');")
time.sleep(5)
elements = driver.find_element_by_name('class="questionNumber"')
```

but it just tells me that this is a illegal method any ideas to fix?

```
<tt-questionnaire _nghost-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted"
  ><kendo-dialog
    _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
    id="questionnaireModal"
    class="ng-tns-c62-66 k-dialog-wrapper ng-star-inserted"
    tabindex="0"
    dir="ltr"
    ><div
      class="k-overlay ng-tns-c62-66 ng-trigger ng-trigger-overlayAppear"
    ></div>
    <div
      role="dialog"
      class="k-widget k-window k-dialog ng-tns-c62-66 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogSlideInAppear"
    >
      <!----><!---->
      <div class="k-content k-window-content k-dialog-content ng-tns-c62-66">
        <div
          _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
          id="questionnaireContainer"
          class="ng-tns-c62-66 ng-star-inserted"
          style=""
        >
          <!---->
          <div
            _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
            id="questionnaire"
            class="ng-star-inserted"
            style=""
          >
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireHeader">
              <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="title">
                <span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="class"
                  >Grundstoff<!----><!----><!----></span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="questionNumber"
                  >1.2.05-101</span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="currentQuestion"
                  >Aufgabe 1</span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="points">Punkte: 4</span>
              </div>
              <ul _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="languageSelection">
                <tt-language-dropdown _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" _nghost-nbk-c241=""
                  ><!----></tt-language-dropdown
                >
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireContent">
              <!----><tt-questionnaire-question
                _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                _nghost-nbk-c270=""
                class="ng-star-inserted"
                ><h2 _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="question">
                  <tt-tts _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                    ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                      <span _ngcontent-nbk-c270=""
                        >Wo ist das Überholen verboten?</span
                      >
                    </div>
                    <!----></tt-tts
                  >
                </h2>
                <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="row mb-3">
                  <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="col-6 mediaContainer">
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                  <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="col-6 answer">
                    <tt-questionnaire-selection-question
                      _ngcontent-nbk-c270=""
                      _nghost-nbk-c268=""
                      class="ng-star-inserted"
                      ><div
                        _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                        class="selectionQuestionContainer"
                      >
                        <!---->
                        <ul _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="answers">
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox1"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox1"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >In allen Einbahnstraßen</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox2"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox2"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >Wo die Verkehrslage unklar ist</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox3"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox3"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >Wo der Gegenverkehr behindert werden
                                    könnte</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <!---->
                        </ul>
                      </div></tt-questionnaire-selection-question
                    ><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!----><!----></tt-questionnaire-question
              ><!---->
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireButtons">
              <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="questionsLeft">
                <span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted"
                  ><i
                    _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                    class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"
                  ></i
                  ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted"
                    >noch 30 Aufgaben</span
                  ><!----><!----></span
                ><!---->
              </div>
              <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="buttons">
                <button
                  _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                  class="finishQuestionnaire ng-star-inserted"
                >
                  Abgabe</button
                ><!----><!----><button
                  _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                  class="markQuestion ng-star-inserted"
                >
                  Markieren</button
                ><!----><!----><button
                  _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                  class="nextQuestion ng-star-inserted"
                >
                  Weiter</button
                ><!----><!----><!----><button
                  _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                  class="showExplanation ng-star-inserted"
                >
                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="">Erklärung</span
                  ><span
                    _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                    class="k-icon k-i-question"
                  ></span></button
                ><!---->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!----><!----><!---->
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireNav">
              <div
                _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                id="questionnaireNavClasses"
                class="ng-star-inserted"
              >
                <button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="active ng-star-inserted">
                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted"
                    >Grundstoff</span
                  ><!----><!----><!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  <!----><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted"
                    >B</span
                  ><!----><!----></button
                ><!---->
              </div>
              <!---->
              <div
                _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                id="questionnaireNavButtons"
                class="ng-star-inserted"
              >
                <button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted active">
                  1
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  2
                  <i
                    _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                    class="fa fa-play-circle-o video ng-star-inserted"
                  ></i
                  ><!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  3
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  4
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  5
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  6
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  7
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  8
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  9
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  10
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  11
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  12
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  13
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  14
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  15
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  16
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  17
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  18
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  19
                  <!----></button
                ><button _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                  20
                  <!----></button
                ><!---->
              </div>
              <!---->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
        <!----><!---->
      </div>
      <!----><!---->
    </div></kendo-dialog
  ><!----></tt-questionnaire
>
```

If you find a way let me know I would also +rep it :)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you use `find_element_by_name` with value `'class="questionNumber"'`? This value is NOT `name`, and it is NOT even `class`. Besides this HTML doesn't have any `name="..."`. If you want to search by class then you need `find_element_by_class("questionNumber")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you also switch driver handles to the new tab

Comment: Thank you @arundeep-chohan. i forgot to switch driver handels now it works

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes in one line.

First: there is no `name="..."` in HTML, and if you want to use `'class="questionNumber"'` then you have to use `find_element_by_class()` instead of `find_element_by_name()`

Second: this function needs only `"questionNumber"` without `class=`

```
find_element_by_class("questionNumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[19132:16448:0529/222120.901:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:21:20.901] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
C:\Users\Night\Desktop\idk.py:10: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  lol = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
C:\Users\Night\Desktop\idk.py:12: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  lol = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
C:\Users\Night\Desktop\idk.py:14: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_xpath is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath) instead
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
C:\Users\Night\Desktop\idk.py:18: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_class_name is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name) instead
  elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name("questionNumber")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Night\Desktop\idk.py", line 18, in <module>
    elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name("questionNumber")
  File "C:\Users\Night\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 766, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Night\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1251, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Night\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Night\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".questionNumber"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x0079D953+2414931]
        Ordinal0 [0x0072F5E1+1963489]
        Ordinal0 [0x0061C6B8+837304]
        Ordinal0 [0x00649500+1021184]
        Ordinal0 [0x0064979B+1021851]
        Ordinal0 [0x00676502+1205506]
        Ordinal0 [0x006644E4+1131748]
        Ordinal0 [0x00674812+1198098]
        Ordinal0 [0x006642B6+1131190]
        Ordinal0 [0x0063E860+976992]
        Ordinal0 [0x0063F756+980822]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00A0CC62+2510274]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x009FF760+2455744]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0082EABA+551962]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0082D916+547446]
        Ordinal0 [0x00735F3B+1990459]
        Ordinal0 [0x0073A898+2009240]
        Ordinal0 [0x0073A985+2009477]
        Ordinal0 [0x00743AD1+2046673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x762FFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x772A7A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x772A7A4E+238]
```

Since everyone asking for the full Error report

here is the full log @furas

i tried your method about here but it doesnt seems to work

here is the code from the website

```
<div class="k-content k-window-content k-dialog-content ng-tns-c62-66">
        <div
          _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
          id="questionnaireContainer"
          class="ng-tns-c62-66 ng-star-inserted"
          style=""
        >
          <!---->
          <div
            _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
            id="questionnaire"
            class="ng-star-inserted"
            style=""
          >
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireHeader">
              <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="title">
                <span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="class"
                  >Grundstoff<!----><!----><!----></span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="questionNumber"
                  >1.2.05-101</span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="currentQuestion"
                  >Aufgabe 1</span
                ><span _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="points">Punkte: 4</span>
              </div>
              <ul _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" class="languageSelection">
                <tt-language-dropdown _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" _nghost-nbk-c241=""
                  ><!----></tt-language-dropdown
                >
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-nbk-c271="" id="questionnaireContent">
              <!----><tt-questionnaire-question
                _ngcontent-nbk-c271=""
                _nghost-nbk-c270=""
                class="ng-star-inserted"
                ><h2 _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="question">
                  <tt-tts _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                    ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                      <span _ngcontent-nbk-c270=""
                        >Wo ist das Überholen verboten?</span
                      >
                    </div>
                    <!----></tt-tts
                  >
                </h2>
                <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="row mb-3">
                  <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="col-6 mediaContainer">
                    <!----><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                  <div _ngcontent-nbk-c270="" class="col-6 answer">
                    <tt-questionnaire-selection-question
                      _ngcontent-nbk-c270=""
                      _nghost-nbk-c268=""
                      class="ng-star-inserted"
                      ><div
                        _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                        class="selectionQuestionContainer"
                      >
                        <!---->
                        <ul _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="answers">
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox1"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox1"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >In allen Einbahnstraßen</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox2"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox2"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >Wo die Verkehrslage unklar ist</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <li _ngcontent-nbk-c268="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                            <span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerCheckbox ng-star-inserted"
                              ><input
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                type="checkbox"
                                autocomplete="off"
                                id="answerCheckbox3"
                                class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" /><label
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                for="answerCheckbox3"
                              ></label></span
                            ><!----><span
                              _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                              class="answerSelectionText ng-star-inserted"
                              ><tt-tts
                                _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                _nghost-nbk-c243=""
                                ><div _ngcontent-nbk-c243="">
                                  <span _ngcontent-nbk-c268=""
                                    >Wo der Gegenverkehr behindert werden
                                    könnte</span
                                  >
                                </div>
                                <!----></tt-tts
                              ></span
                            ><!----><!---->
                          </li>
                          <!---->
                        </ul>
                      </div></tt-questionnaire-selection-question
                    ><!----><!---->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!----><!----></tt-questionnaire-question
              ><!---->
            </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).